# why cant I access XGBClassifier feature_importances_ from a child class?

Tags: python, oop, scikit-learn, xgboost

I've been busting my head over this quirk behavior of XGBClassifier which is supposed to behave nicely like RandomForestClassifier does:

```
import xgboost as xgb 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

class my_rf(RandomForestClassifier):
    def important_features(self, X):
        return super(RandomForestClassifier, self).feature_importances_         

class my_xgb(xgb.XGBClassifier):
    def important_features(self, X):
        return super(xgb.XGBClassifier, self).feature_importances_          

c1 = my_rf()
c1.fit(X,y)
c1.important_features(X) #works
```

while this code fails :(

```
c2 = my_xgb()
c2.fit(X,y)
c2.important_features(X) #fails with AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'
```

I stared at both code bits and they look the same to me! what am I missing??
Sorry if this is noob, python OOP mysteries are just beyond me.

[rf-code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L708)

[xgb-code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py)

EDIT:

If I use vanilla xgb, without inheriting, everything works nicely:

```
import xgboost as xgb
print "version:", xgb.__version__
c = xgb.XGBClassifier()
c.fit(X_train.as_matrix(), y_train.label)
print c.feature_importances_[:5]            

version: 0.4
[ 0.4039548   0.05932203  0.06779661  0.00847458  0.        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `feature_importances_` isn't implemented in XGBoost. You could roll your own using something like permutation feature importance:

```
import random
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score

def feature_importances(clf, X, y):
    score = np.mean(cross_val_score(clf, X,y,scoring='roc_auc'))
    importances = {} 
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        X_perm = X.copy()
        X_perm[:,i] = random.sample(X[:,i].tolist(), X.shape[0])
        perm_score = np.mean(cross_val_score(clf, X_perm , y, scoring='roc_auc'))
        importances[i] = score - perm_score

    return importances
```

Comment: are you sure? did you take a look at https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py

Comment: i'm using an older version of xgboost, version 0.40 (i can't build the current version of master), what version are you running (check `xgboost.__version__`)

Answer (score 1):

The output shows code is on version 0.4 and [repository tree of last stable version of 0.4x](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/0.47) (released `Jan 15, 2016`) shows [sklearn.py](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/0.47/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py) file does not have `feature_importances_` yet.
This feature was actually introduced in [this](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/commit/31c0408cb4d33b4d9725a2448cd888b2643dcc01#diff-2c197a11c1b576e821f5942be9eab74c) commit on `Feb 8, 2016`.

I cloned current github repository, built and installed `xgboost` from scratch and code works fine:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble.forest import RandomForestClassifier
import xgboost as xgb
print "version:", xgb.__version__

class my_rf(RandomForestClassifier):
    def important_features(self, X):
        return super(RandomForestClassifier, self).feature_importances_ 

class my_xgb(xgb.XGBClassifier):
    def important_features(self, X):
        return super(xgb.XGBClassifier, self).feature_importances_

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

c1 = my_rf()
c1.fit(X,y)
print c1.important_features(X)

c2 = my_xgb()
c2.fit(X,y)
print c2.important_features(X)

c3 = xgb.XGBClassifier()
c3.fit(X, y)
print c3.feature_importances_
```

Output:

```
version: 0.6
[ 0.11834481  0.02627218  0.57008797  0.28529505]
[ 0.17701453  0.11228534  0.41479525  0.29590487]
[ 0.17701453  0.11228534  0.41479525  0.29590487]
```

### Edit:

If you're using `XGBRegressor` make sure you cloned the repository after `Dec 1, 2016` because according to [this](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/commit/dd477ac903eb6f658d6fb2984763c3f8a4516389) commit that's when `feature_importances_` was moved to `base XGBModel` for `XGBRegressor` access.

added this to above code:

```
class my_xgb_regressor(xgb.XGBRegressor):
    def important_features(self, X):
        return super(xgb.XGBRegressor, self).feature_importances_

c4 = my_xgb_regressor()
c4.fit(X, y)
print c4.important_features(X)
```

Output:

```
version: 0.6
[ 0.0307026   0.01456868  0.45198349  0.50274523]
[ 0.17701453  0.11228534  0.41479525  0.29590487]
[ 0.17701453  0.11228534  0.41479525  0.29590487]
[ 0.25        0.17518248  0.34489051  0.229927  ]
```

Comment: @user308827 It's strange. Let me check again

Comment: Also, I am using XGBRegressor()

Comment: @user308827 I also suggest not using pip install if you're using that. instead clone the repo and build it yourself.